# CSS Child Menu LI Forcing Parent's Width to Increase

Tags: css

So I know almost exactly what I need to do, but I don't know *how* I need to do it.

I have a drop down menu that opens when you hover over it. The child is causing the width of the parent to increase when you hover over it and that is not what I want. I know I need to set the child to position absolutely... but when I do it the child no longer shows up and it appears the hover on the parent no longer functions. Can anyone help figure out where exactly the absolute position part needs to go in? You can see I have something that I commented out.

I'd like the child to be aligned at the bottom right of the "Action" drop down.

I also have a problem where if I set the padding / margin on the parent. It extends to child. I believe I can solve that either with the absolute positioning, or after that is solved.

Here is my HTML:

```
<br />
<div style="width: 90%; margin:auto; background-color:#CCC; height:36px;">
<div id="actions">
    <ul>
        <li class="action_arrow_down"><a href="#">Actions</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class = "separated_action"><a href="#">Separated Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}

#actions {
float: right;
display: block;
background-color: #4d90fe;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#actions ul{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

#actions li ul {
display: none;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: #CCC 1px solid;
/*position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;*/

}

#actions li ul li {
    display: block;
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #000000; 
overflow: hidden;
}

#actions li ul li:hover, #actions li ul li a:hover {
background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#actions li ul li a {
color: #000000; 
}

#actions li{
line-height: 36px;
list-style: none;   
font-size: 14px;
text-indent: 15px;
}

#actions li:not(ul li){
background-color: #4d90fe;
}

#actions li:not(ul li):hover {
background-color: #0362fd;  
}

#actions li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

#actions li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
display:block;
}

#actions li ul li {
display: block; 
}

.separated_action {
border-top: #CCC 1px solid; 
}

/*.action_arrow_down {
background-image: url('images/action_arrow_down.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right center;
}*/
```

The code is probably very convoluted and could use some cleaning up. I'll remove redundant parts once I get the sub menu working how I want.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7yQa/).

Comment: I am not sure if I do follow your question exactly, but if you add a width property to #actions would that not give you what you wanted? E.G. http://jsfiddle.net/u7yQa/6/

Comment: @ jacob - but then width of child will b crash..

Comment: @JacobvanLingen I actually want the parent to have as small of a width as possible. The child also needs to adjust to width of the content in the box. No wordwrap. It works currently, with the exception of the on:hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already had it. That you "loose" your submenu when you position it absolute, is because you position the parent relatively.

Solution is to remove that line:

```
#actions ul{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    /*position: relative; <-- delete this line */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#actions li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: #CCC 1px solid;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: -80px;
}
```

Check your [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/u7yQa/9/).

Adjust the `margin-left` to shift the submenu left or right. By default the left side of the parent is the left side of the child. If you'd give the child a fix width, you could use a negative margin-left to align the right sides.

Check your [**2nd updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/u7yQa/11/).

Comment: Thanks! I thought I **had** to have the parent be relative for the child to be absolute.

Comment: No, when you place a div absolute, the value of top, bottom, left and right will be relative to the body. If you place that same div into a relative positioned div, the top, bottom, left and right value of the child will be relativ to the parent (and not the body)